# PHP, how to log out an account? Is session_destroy helpful?

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables, logout

How can i code the account log out in my system. I have used header() to return it back to the index page and destroy all the session variables exist. It destroys the session but it returns to the previous page with no session variables (such as username) what is the best way to do this logout module of my website?

Comment: _“but it returns to the previous page with no session variables (such as username)”_ – why should it have such values, when the user just very specifically logged out …?

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  Do you want to keep on remembering the username after destroying the session?  What I do when logging out is to record my logout time etc. in a MySQL database, then I unset and destroy my entire session as well as delete the session cookie.  Other pages which require session information should return an error alert or redirect to some page, if there is no valid session present.

Comment: Hi Stefan! Such a great help :) I just want to display an invalid page if i want to click back button on the browser saying that 'you have already exited the website/logout', so the best thing is in every page i will require a session variable?

Comment: Thanks - I made an edit to my post. On pages that must only be displayed during login, I would have a check for a valid session right at the top. If that check returns false you can just redirect to the message page you want, or show an alert and hide the rest of the page, or whatever you'd like to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply empty the `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less what I do:

Every page that requires a valid login before it should be shown, is checked for valid session variables as well as a corresponding active login session record in the database.  If those conditions are not met, the user gets redirected with an error alert.

```
<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>
```

In *logout.php*:

```
function deleteSessionCookie() {
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
            $params["path"], $params["domain"],
            $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
        );
    }
}

function deleteSessionIfExists() {
    if (session_id() != "") {
        $_SESSION = array();
        deleteSessionCookie();
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }
}

session_start();

// record logout dateTime in db
// Update existing record using $_SESSION["loginCode"] set during login.

deleteSessionIfExists();

// redirect to index page of website
```

EDIT:  At the top of pages requiring a login, I would have something like this:

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION["loginCode"]) || empty($_SESSION["userCode"]))
    header('index.php?alert=Invalid session');
```

In my case I also check for the presence of many other session variables I created during login, and I also check the session values for consistency with the database. (I put all the tests into a function, for example `isValidSession()` which returns either true or false, which I can easily include on every page where needed.)